# Using imline with uiaxes

Tags: matlab, interactive, axes, matlab-gui, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to design an app using Matlab 2017b with `appdesigner`. I want to attach a movable line to an image using the `imline` function. However, `appdesigner` appear to use a new type of object, `uiaxes`, whereas the `imline` function will only use the object `axes`.

Example of command that does work:

```
figure; taxes = axes;  imline(taxes, [0 0], [0 1]);
```

Example of a command that does not work:

```
figure; tuiaxes = uiaxes;  imline(tuiaxes, [0 0], [0 1]);
```

**Questions**

Is there a workaround for using `imline` with appdesigner? Is it still possible to use the old `axes` object? Is there some other way to have interactive lines on GUIs using the `appdesigner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the underlying "old `axes` object" of a `uiaxes`, all we need to do is `struct(tuiaxes).Axes`. Moving on - I tried playing around with this in R2018b, and I have some good and some bad news.

- The good news is that one *can* add a `imline` to a MATLAB figure by modifying the `imline` function (`<MATLAB>\R2018b\toolbox\images\imuitools\imline.m`) function a bit.
- The bad news is that it will not have most of the functionality that you might be used to.

Here are the very basic steps:

1. Create a copy of `imline.m`, let's call it `ui_imline.m`.
2. Comment out lines 260-261 (related to `cmenu`), and line 317 (`updateAncestorListeners(...)`).
3. Modify your code as follows:

   ```
   uifigure; tuiaxes = uiaxes; ui_imline(struct(tuiaxes).Axes, [0 0], [0 1]);
   ```

This will result in:

[image]

If you want any other functionality besides dragging, you'll likely have to rewrite all uifigure-incompatible bits of `imline` yourself, or wait for an unknown future release that would do it for you.

Comment: Wow, what an insightful answer. For future users, would you mind posting the commented lines in case the function gets updated in the future?

Comment: I hear you, thing is - it's copyrighted code, so I'm not sure I can post it here w/o breaking some rule of SO.